# 'GuzzleHttp\Collection' not found

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to [use this Google Analytics API tutori](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php)al, but it's dependent on Guzzle. And I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Collection' not found in ../google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php on line 93
```

But I already installed Guzzle:

```
>>php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~5.2
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing react/promise (v2.2.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing guzzlehttp/streams (3.0.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing guzzlehttp/ringphp (1.1.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (5.3.0)
    Downloading: 100%         

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

And this is my composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "google/auth": "v0.3",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "5.3.*"
    },
```

Comment: The google analytics library has its own `composer.json` file. Have you tried running `composer install`?

Comment: yes, this composer is the one that I shown on the question. Yes I tried, and it shows several commands.

Comment: Are you including the composer-generated autoload php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include Composer's autoload file, as described here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

In your main file, add the following line at the top (before any of your code that requires those files):

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```